# Извлечь изображение из кэша

Tags: google-chrome, изображения, кэширование, браузер

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста, как извлечь изображение из кэша Google Chrome? И как? Думаю, есть какие-то папки на жестком диске?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть в "Temporary Internet Files". На семерке путь *C:\Users\**Ваша учетка**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5*, там должны быть временные папки.

Comment: В Win XP расположение такое:
C:\Documents and Settings\УЧЕТКА\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files

Comment: хром хранит кэш не в этой папке. У него своя папка с кэшем

Answer (score 3):

`chrome://cache` - просмотр ссылок.

`c:\Users\имя_вашего_юзера\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\` - файлы.

`VideoCacheView` - чтобы фильтровать, выгружать и просматривать.

Comment: спасибо, помогло! Были бы вы активным участником, дал бы вам баунти.

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто: в папке

```
c:\Users\имя_вашего_юзера\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\
```

ищите по содержимому **JFIF** для jpg, **PNG** для png, **GIF89** для gif, копируете их куда-нибудь и приделываете к ним соответствующее расширение.

Answer (score 0):

конечно может не оригинально, но как факт, наберите в адресной строке браузера chrome://cache

Answer (score 0):

chrome://cache/ 
или about:cache

Comment: К сожалению, там хранятся ответы серверов на HTTP запросы, и чтобы, например, посмотреть картинку, придется написать прогу, которая распарсит такой ответ и сгенерирует изображение. Вряд ли это осилит большинство тех, кто просмотрел этот вопрос... Хотя если это все-таки сделать, то нужное изображение станет гораздо легче искать, ибо теперь имеется их URL.

Comment: Это упростит поиск изображения по дате и названию url, а дальше искать в кэше будет проще.

Comment: Ничего не нужно писать, указанная в соседнем ответе программа VideoCacheView делает это всё.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu:

```
/home/username/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache
```